# SQL sub query will not SUM

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

This is a query I am creating. It works but gives to results - one for invoices and one for credits. I only want one result - the total. i.e. invoices less credit notes.

```
SELECT 
sum ([linetotal])
FROM
(
SELECT
sum(t1.[LineTotal])  AS 'Linetotal'
FROM OINV T0  
INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN OSLP T2 ON T0.SlpCode = T2.SlpCode 
WHERE t0.taxdate >= '20170101' and t0.taxdate <= '20170131'  and t0.[canceled] ='n' and  T0.[SlpCODE] = '4'

union all

SELECT
sum(-T1.[LineTotal] ) AS 'Linetotal'
FROM ORIN T0 
INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN OSLP T2 ON T0.SlpCode = T2.SlpCode 
WHERE t0.taxdate >= '20170101' and t0.taxdate <= '20170131'  and t0.[canceled] ='n' and  T0.[SlpCODE] = '4'
)
as a
group by a.linetotal
```

Comment: Show your current result and your expected result.

Comment: Can you please validate an answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove group by.

```
SELECT 
sum ([linetotal])
FROM
(
SELECT
sum(t1.[LineTotal])  AS 'Linetotal'
FROM OINV T0  
INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN OSLP T2 ON T0.SlpCode = T2.SlpCode 
WHERE t0.taxdate >= '20170101' and t0.taxdate <= '20170131'  and t0.[canceled] ='n' and  T0.[SlpCODE] = '4'

union all

SELECT
sum(-T1.[LineTotal] ) AS 'Linetotal'
FROM ORIN T0 
INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN OSLP T2 ON T0.SlpCode = T2.SlpCode 
WHERE t0.taxdate >= '20170101' and t0.taxdate <= '20170131'  and t0.[canceled] ='n' and  T0.[SlpCODE] = '4'
)
as a
```

Comment: If it is helpful, you don't forget award.

Comment: The award is often forgotten those days :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the last line : `group by a.linetotal` because it's separating them since they are not equals